# fortran gives strange results when writing to file

Tags: fortran

I am using fortran. I want to write some information to a file, and here is my code:

```
    open(unit=114514, position="append", file="msst_info.txt")
        write(114514, 100) "step =", step
        write(114514, 200) "A =", A
        write(114514, 200) "omega =", omega(sd)
        write(114514, 300) "dilation =", dilation(sd)
        write(114514, 200) "p_msst =", p_msst / (kBar * 10)
        write(114514, 300) "vol =", vol / Ang**3
        write(114514, 300) "temp =", temperature
        write(114514, 400) "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        100 format(A10, i8)
        200 format(A10, e12.4)
        300 format(A10, f12.4)
        400 format(A)
        close(114514)
```

I wish it can append the information to this file after each step. But the result is very strange:

```
dilation =      0.9999
  p_msst =  0.3619E+02
     vol =   10       A = -0.1041E-23
   omega = -0.2290E-15
dilation =      0.9999
  p_msst =  0.3619E+02
     vol        A = -0.1041E-23
   omega = -0.2290E-15
dilation =      0.9999
  p_msst =  0.3619E+02
     vol =   1053.0452
    temp =    195.9830
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    step =       6
       A = -0.1041E-23
   omega = -0.2290E-15
dilation =      0.9999
  p_msst =  0.3619E+02
     vol =   1053.0452
    temp =    195.9830
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    step =       7
       A = -0.1249E    step =       7
       A = -0.1249E-23
   omega = -0.2290E-15
dilation =      0.9999
  p_msst =  0.4342E+02
     vol =   1052.8163
    temp =    198.4668
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

the format of step 6 is what i want. but in step 7, some text is written multiple times, and their position is completely wrong. I wonder why it happens.

the whole code:

```
module msst
use poscar_struct_def
use dynconstr
use prec
use reader_tags
use poscar
implicit none

contains
subroutine msst_step(dyn, latt_cur, t_info, tsif, tifor, io, niond, nionpd, ntypd, ntyppd)
! =======================================================================
! Written by S. Pan 2021/5/28 
! This subroutine calculate a msst step. (Evan J. Reed 2003 PRL)
! I refer to fix_msst.cpp in LAMMPS when writing this code. 
! The v(t-dt/2) is needed for velocity verlet algo.
! Two step: first, calculate the velocity v(t) with the a(t) and v(t-dt/2).
! second: give the position of ion and cell x(t+dt), and v(t+dt/2).
! The parameter mu is neglected since it makes the process complex.
! dyn: the struct for some MD variables, such as x, v, force.
! t_info: the struct for type information, such as number of ions.
! step: the current number of step. Init if step == 1.
! =======================================================================

    ! the dyn info will be changed
    type(dynamics), intent(in out) :: dyn
    type(latt), intent(in out) :: latt_cur
    type(type_info), intent(in out) :: t_info

    ! these are inputs, should not be modified     
    type(in_struct), intent(in) :: io
    real(q), dimension(3, t_info%nions), intent(in) :: tifor ! force on ions
    real(q), dimension(3, 3), intent(in) :: tsif ! stress

    ! some units
    real(q), parameter :: eV = 1.60218e-19, Ang = 1e-10, fs = 1e-15, &
                       amu = 1.66053886e-27, kBar = 1e5, kB =  1.38064852e-23
                       ! energy in J, length in meter, time in s, mass in kg
                       ! stress in Pa
    ! internal variables
    real(q), save :: dt, dthalf, tscale, qmass, vs, total_mass=0, vol0
 
    real(q), dimension(3, t_info%nions) :: velocity_before_half_dt, velocity_now, velocity_after_half_dt, &
                                        C_force, x

    real(q), dimension(3), save :: omega = [0, 0, 0] ! the time derivative of cell
    real(q), dimension(3) :: dilation = [1, 1, 1]
    integer :: ierr, ii, ni, nt, niond, nionpd, ntypd, ntyppd
    integer, save :: sd, step = 0
    real(q), dimension(3, 3) :: kinetic_stress, total_stress
    real(q), dimension(3, 3), save :: p0 
    real(q) :: p_msst, A, vol, vol1, vol2, fac1, sqrt_initial_temperature_scaling, temperature, ekin
    
    if (step .eq. 0) then
        dyn%init = 0
        call rd_poscar(latt_cur, t_info, dyn, &
     &           niond, nionpd, ntypd, ntyppd, &
     &           io%iu0, io%iu6)
    end if

    dyn%posioc = dyn%posion
    step = step + 1
    dt = dyn%potim * fs
    dthalf = dt/2
    
    ! convert x to cartsian coordination. x and velocity use standard unit.
    do ii = 1, 3
        x(ii, :) = dyn%posion(ii, :) * latt_cur%a(ii, ii) * Ang
    end do

    ! there isn't anything in dyn%pomass. so must use t_info%pomass
    ni=1
    do nt=1,t_info%ntyp
        do ni=ni,t_info%nityp(nt)+ni-1
            C_force(:, ni) = tifor(:, ni)/t_info%pomass(nt)
            total_mass = total_mass + t_info%pomass(nt)
        enddo
    enddo
    C_force = C_force * (eV/Ang/amu)
    total_mass = total_mass * amu

    if (step .eq. 1) then
        ! read these tags from INCAR
        call process_incar(io%lopen, io%iu0, io%iu5, 'qmass', qmass, ierr, .true.)
        call process_incar(io%lopen, io%iu0, io%iu5, 'tscale', tscale, ierr, .true.)
        call process_incar(io%lopen, io%iu0, io%iu5, 'shock_direction', sd, ierr, .true.)
        call process_incar(io%lopen, io%iu0, io%iu5, 'shock_velocity', vs, ierr, .true.)
        ! use tscale to give a initial cell velocity, or the cell will stay still forever        
        do ii = 1, 3
            velocity_now(ii, :) = dyn%vel(ii, :) * latt_cur%a(ii, ii) * (Ang/fs) / dyn%potim
        end do
        
        CALL EKINC(EKIN,T_INFO%NIONS,T_INFO%NTYP,T_INFO%ITYP,T_INFO%POMASS,DYN%POTIM,LATT_CUR%A,DYN%VEL)
        temperature = 2 * ekin * eV / (kB * t_info%nions * 3 )

        fac1 = tscale*total_mass/qmass*temperature
        omega(sd) = -sqrt(fac1)
        sqrt_initial_temperature_scaling = sqrt(1.0-tscale)
        velocity_now = velocity_now * sqrt_initial_temperature_scaling    
    else
        ! =======================================================================
        ! 2nd half of Verlet update. this part get current velocity from t-dt/2.
        ! =======================================================================

        ! propagate particle velocities 1/2 step, it should not be done on the first step of MD.
        do ii = 1, 3
            velocity_before_half_dt(ii, :) = dyn%vel(ii, :) * latt_cur%a(ii, ii) * (Ang/fs) / dyn%potim
        end do
        velocity_now = velocity_before_half_dt + C_force*dthalf
    end if

    ! compute new pressure and volume and temperature
    call compute_kinetic_stress(t_info, latt_cur, dyn, kinetic_stress, tsif, -1)
    total_stress = tsif + kinetic_stress
    total_stress = total_stress * kBar
    vol = latt_cur%a(1, 1) * latt_cur%a(2, 2) * latt_cur%a(3, 3) * (Ang**3)

    if (step .eq. 1) then
        p0 = total_stress
        vol0 = vol
    end if

    p_msst = vs**2 * total_mass * (vol0 - vol)/vol0**2
    A = total_mass * (total_stress(sd, sd) - p0(sd, sd) - p_msst) / qmass
    ! qmass is in mass(kg)**2 / length(m)**4
    
    if (step .ne. 1) then
    ! propagate the time derivative of the volume 1/2 step at fixed V, r, rdot
    ! it should not be done on the first step of MD.
        omega(sd) = omega(sd) + A*dthalf ! this is the current omega
    end if

    ! =======================================================================
    ! 1st half of Verlet update
    ! in VASP, the 1st half of Verlet update cannot be performed before 
    ! compute force and stress. So it must be placed here.
    ! =======================================================================

    ! propagate the time derivative of the volume 1/2 step at fixed vol, r, rdot
    omega(sd) = omega(sd) + A*dthalf ! this is omega(t+dt/2)
    ! propagate velocities 1/2 step 
    velocity_after_half_dt = velocity_now + C_force*dthalf

    ! now, we need to compute the vol and pos for next step:

    ! propagate the volume 1/2 step
    vol1 = vol + omega(sd)*dthalf
    ! rescale positions and change box size
    dilation(sd) = vol1/vol
    call remap(latt_cur, sd, x, velocity_after_half_dt, dilation,t_info)
    ! propagate particle positions 1 time step
    x = x + dt * velocity_after_half_dt
    ! propagate the volume 1/2 step
    vol2 = vol1 + omega(sd)*dthalf
    ! rescale positions and change box size
    dilation(sd) = vol2/vol1
    call remap(latt_cur, sd, x, velocity_after_half_dt, dilation,t_info)

    do ii = 1, 3
        dyn%posion(ii, :) = x(ii, :) / latt_cur%a(ii, ii) / Ang
        dyn%vel(ii, :) = velocity_after_half_dt(ii, :) / latt_cur%a(ii, ii) / (Ang/fs) * dyn%potim
    end do
    t_info%posion = dyn%posion

    CALL EKINC(EKIN,T_INFO%NIONS,T_INFO%NTYP,T_INFO%ITYP,T_INFO%POMASS,DYN%POTIM,LATT_CUR%A,DYN%VEL)
    temperature = 2 * ekin * eV / (kB * t_info%nions * 3 )

    ! this block for debug. write the information to a file
    if (.true.) then
        open(unit=114514, position="append", file="msst_info.txt")
        write(114514, 100) "step =", step
        write(114514, 200) "A =", A
        write(114514, 200) "omega =", omega(sd)
        write(114514, 300) "dilation =", dilation(sd)
        write(114514, 200) "p_msst =", p_msst / (kBar * 10)
        write(114514, 300) "vol =", vol / Ang**3
        write(114514, 300) "temp =", temperature
        write(114514, 400) "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        100 format(A10, i8)
        200 format(A10, e12.4)
        300 format(A10, f12.4)
        400 format(A)
        close(114514)
    end if
end subroutine msst_step


! change the shape of cell, along with ion pos and vel.
subroutine remap(latt_cur, sd, x, v, dilation,t_info)
    integer, intent(in):: sd
    type(type_info), intent(in) :: t_info
    real(q), dimension(3), intent(in) :: dilation

    real(q), dimension(3, t_info%nions), intent(in out) :: x, v
    type(latt), intent(in out) :: latt_cur

    latt_cur%a(sd, sd) = dilation(sd) *  latt_cur%a(sd, sd)
    x(sd, :) = dilation(sd) * x(sd, :)
    v(sd, :) = dilation(sd) * v(sd, :)
end subroutine remap

end module msst
```

Comment: We really need more code from you. Show us a piece of code we can actually try. See also [mcve] and [ask]. It is really very important. Are you using multiple threads or multiple processes? Which compiler? Which operating system? How does the complete loop with the steps look like?

Comment: This code is a extenstion to a large program (vasp) with mpi. The subroutine is call by the main program every step. I use intel compilier on Linux. I tried change the io unit to a file created by the main program, then it can work correctly. I will post my code below. Thank you!

Comment: It looks as though multiple processes are writing to the same file - are you running it as multiple processes, or on just one process? The most likely solution is to just get mpi rank zero to open and write the file, but with what you have said so far I can't quite be 100% sure

Comment: Yes, do not do the writing with all your MPI ranks. Do it with one MPI rank only.